# Display the text from specific cells of another excel tab into one column - I need an updated version of TAB!CELL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with the tab "Content" and tab "Review". I want to display/show the text from specific cells from the tab "Content" in a specific column one below the other in the tab "Review"

So for example:
From tab "Content": C2 - E2 - G2 - I2 and so on until AO2 (basically every two cells from row 2 but starting from C2 - these have content I need to show in the tab "Review")

In tab "Review" I want each of the above cells to display in Column B one below the other, so from B2, B3, B4, B5... until B21 (which corresponds to the total amount I will be taking from tab "Content")

Since I used to have little content, I did it manually by putting into Column B in the tab "Review" the following simple "formulas" starting from B2: Content!C2, in B3: Content!E2... and so on.

Now I have a lot of content and cannot do this manually for each cell. Also, since it is every two cells I cannot just copy down the formula as it will not recognize every 2-cell parameter.

I might need to apply this same pattern for other rows as well in the future. Only the row number would change, and therefore I need to optimize the formula.

Visual short example:

Tab Content

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -------- | LAN | TITLE 1 | -------- | TITLE 2 | -------- | TITLE 3 |
| -------- | EN | LION K | -------- | RAISING | -------- | DRAGON |
| -------- | EN | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |

In Tab Review I want:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| DESCRIPT | CONTENT |
| TITLE 1 | LION K |
| TITLE 2 | RAISING |
| TITLE 3 | DRAGON |

I already tried some formulas (offset, index...) I adapted but I kept getting something wrong: "There's a problem with this formula".

I am using Excel from Microsoft 365

Comment: `=TAKE(WRAPROWS(Content!C2:AO2,2),,1)`?

Answer (score 1):

With formula

`=VSTACK({"DESCRIPT","CONTENT","ADDED"},WRAPROWS(TOROW(Content!C1:AO3,1,TRUE),3))`

where adjust C1:AO3 to the actual size of rows, and number 3 change to the count of rows.

If the intermediate cells are not empty then use this formula:

`=VSTACK({"DESCRIPT","CONTENT","ADDED"},WRAPROWS(TOROW(CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!C1:AO3,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(Sheet1!C1:AO3)/2,1,2)),1,TRUE),3))`

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I deem it unlikely that column D, F H etc are empty. If so, then OP needs to reconfigure how he has set up his data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H10</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, DROP(A4:G6,,2),
     _ColForRev, CHOOSECOLS(_Data,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_Data)-2,1,2)),
     _Output, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TAKE(_ColForRev,2),,1),2),
     VSTACK({"DESCRIPT","CONTENT"},_Output))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function makes it easy to read, create variables thus reducing redundant repeated functions/ranges etc.
- `_Data` variable is the whole data range in this example it is `A4:G6`
- `_ColForRev` refers to columns needed to show in `REVIEW` Tab, using `COLUMNS()` functions gives the number of columns available, using `CHOOSECOLS()` taking the selective columns with the help of the `SEQUENCE()` created.
- `_Output` shows taking the first two rows including the header and the second row, turning it into a single array using `TOCOL()` and then turning it into a `2-dimensional` array using `WRAPROWS()`
- Finally, showing the output using `VSTACK()` along with the headers(hardcoded).

---

The above formula can be simplified more, if you have the `DESCRIPT` Column already created manually and need only the row data from `C2:AO2` then for the `CONTENT` column:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, HSTACK(C5:G5,""),
     TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(_Data,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_Data)/2,1,2))))
```

---

**Note:** Ensure to change the cell references/ranges as per your suit.

---

Use `WRAPROWS()` with `TAKE()` function:

[image]

---

```
=TAKE(WRAPROWS(C5:G5,2),,1)
```

---